# How to autoload bash script on Android?

Tags: android, bash, shell

Autoload i mean when i reboot just like ~/.bash_profile, /etc/bashrc, etc on linux
Where should i place my script?

I have google it but hard to find out.

Comment: You'll find information about how to run things on boot on Android by searching for "Android init system" - I'm not familiar with it so can't really answer your question. Look here for instance: http://elinux.org/Android_Booting

Answer (score 0):

What action you would like to do after reboot? Android uses a broadcast intent `android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED`, which signalizes that the boot has been finished. You can create a `Service`, which will be registered to start by this broadcast and it can make some action you need.

Here you can find an example of such service: [Start Service at boot](http://www.androidcompetencycenter.com/2009/06/start-service-at-boot/)